# Can't get model property from Ember/Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I have an Ember app using the ember-rails gem that can create a record and save it to the database. All but one of the model's properties can render in the template. For some reason the 'image' property isn't being sent when Ember requests it.

new_route.js.coffee

```
App.NewRoute = Ember.Route.extend

    model: ->
        App.Post.createRecord()

    setupController: (controller, model) ->
        controller.set('content', model)
```

new_controller.js.coffee

```
App.NewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    templateName: "new"

    content: 
        title: @title
        image: @image
        body: @body

    actions: 

        createPost: ->
            @content.save()
```

post_route.js.coffee:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: (params) ->
        App.Post.find(params.post_id)
```

post.hbs:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

{{imgtag image}}

{{markdown body}}

<p>{{author}}</p>
```

post.js.coffee

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr 'string'
    image: DS.attr 'string'
    body: DS.attr 'string'
    author: DS.attr 'string'
```

The model has the correct property in Rails console, but the request for it in Ember returns the model without the property even present.

Comment: Does your API call return a value for `image`?

Comment: @chopper It returns the JSON for the model but without the `image` property present.

Comment: Well then it's a problem on your Rails side. Have you made sure that you include :image in your serializer? Could you post relevant code?

Comment: @chopper Perfect. It was missing from the serializer. Thanks for your help, I feel a little stupid now.

Comment: No problem. I'll add this as an answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include :image in your serializer.